# Web Service Reference issue with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I'm having a hard time using Web Service reference with VS2010.
I followed the following instructions:
[Instructions](http://sarangasl.blogspot.fr/2010/09/create-simple-web-service-in-visual.html)

I defined a simple function in my Web Service:

```
namespace WebService1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string HelloWorld(string name)
        {
            return "Hello "+name;
        }

        public double myFunction(double a, double b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

It implements the following Interface:

```
namespace WebService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string HelloWorld(string name);

        [OperationContract]
        double myFunction(double a, double b);
    }
}
```

When I try to call it in my Console App:

```
using WebTest.MyReference;

namespace WebTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Service1 service = new Service1();
            Console.WriteLine(service.HelloWorld("Edouard")); //Works
            double price = service.myFunction(2,3); //Doesn't Work
        }
    }
}
```

VS2010 tells me that myFunction is defined this way:

```
void service1.myFunction(double a, bool aSpecified, double b, bool bSpecified, out double myFunctionResult, out bool myFunctionResultSpecified)
```

Which is clearly not the same use of my function!
How can I be able to call my webservice function like I defined it?

Comment: Please state explicit questions.

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the `using service1` part but the parameters seem totally different ?

Comment: I used: 

using WebTest.MyReference;

WebTest being my console app
MyReference my web reference name

And yes the parameters seems differents that's why I'm confused..

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF will not return an int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964759/wcf-will-not-return-an-int)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question, I think it is the same problem you are having.

[WCF service method arguments, bool specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396190/wcf-service-method-arguments-bool-specified)