# C# function calling a different method

Tags: c#

I created a WCFService and a WindowsFormApp. In the service, I have 3 functions. Two of them takes an integer as parameter and returns a integer. The other takes a string and returns a string.

When I try to call the two functions (in WindowsFormApp) that takes an integer , the program thinks I'm trying to call some other function in "Reference.cs" and not from the service I created. The string function doesn't have this problem and works fine, but the 2 int functions calls some other void function in "Reference.cs".

These are the functions mentioned and the ones I want to call. This file is "Service1.svc.cs"
`

```
    public int c2f(int c)
    {
        int num = c * 9 / 5 + 32;
        return num;
    }

    public int f2c(int f)
    {
        int num = (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
        return num;
    }

    public string sort(string s)
    {
        String str = String.Join(",", s.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).OrderBy(x => x));
        return str;
    }
```

This is the function that it's calling (which is not what I want). This is in "Reference.cs"

```
    public void f2c(int f, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] bool fSpecified, out int f2cResult, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] out bool f2cResultSpecified) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("f2c", new object[] {
                    f,
                    fSpecified});
        f2cResult = ((int)(results[0]));
        f2cResultSpecified = ((bool)(results[1]));
    }
```

I spent a good couple hours trying to fix the problem, but no avail. Could someone please help?

How I'm calling the functions: After adding a button to the WindowsFormApp and double-clicking it, in the button method, I have `Service1 serv = new Service1();`. Then if I were to write `serv.sort("some string")`, it would refer to the function in the first code block, which is what I wanted. If I were to write `serv.f2c(0)`, an error comes up saying I'm missing parameters and upon closer inspection, it tells me that I'm referring to the function in the second code block, which is NOT what I wanted. Hopefully, this gives a little more insight.

Comment: Hi. Please get into the habit of posting code as text, and not as screenshots.

Comment: Do you know how WCF works? The client never calls the server code, you call the endpoint defined for the service. In your case, the way to perform that call is through the autogenerated code that VS creates for you

Comment: Please write your code clearly

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Sorry, I don't really know how WCF works. I'm just trying to learn how to make a basic web service.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What's the autogenerated code that you mentioned? I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: You need to update the service reference. Probably you have a stale reference.cs file generated at the beginning and now no more in sync with your wcf. Search in your Solution Explorer the Service References folder, open it and righ click on the service. Choose Update. This should be done every time you change the interface exposed by the service

Comment: @Steve It was added as a Web Reference. I opened the folder and chose "Update Web Reference", but it didn't fix the problem..

Comment: Are the two "int functions" overloaded? The invocation seems to be passing two arguments (the second one being a `bool`) whereas both methods take only one `int` parameter.

Comment: @EddyYoung That's WCF way of determining whether the value was explicitly set by the server or not (to differentiate a default 0 from an intended 0)

Comment: @pepperguy3 The autogenerated code is the code you posted on the second code block. What happens when you call the function that does work? Can you post how you are calling both methods?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @EddyYoung I don't think it's overloaded. There aren't any duplicate functions with the same name. I'm confused as to why the program would refer to the void function in Reference.cs (the file was probably auto-generated) and not the function I wrote. It works fine for the string function, but not the int functions.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I added the process of how I called both methods in the post.

Comment: Can you post the entire form's code? You have something weird there

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964759/wcf-will-not-return-an-int)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I added the form's code. There really isn't anything yet because of the problem I'm having. The process described in "How I'm calling the functions" would apply to any of the button methods.

Comment: @dashboard I had basically the same problem as the question you linked. It helped fixed the problem I was having. Thanks!

Comment: @pepperguy3 Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Add Service Reference" instead of "Add Web Reference".

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964759/wcf-will-not-return-an-int) helped fix my issue.